# how to prevent the program from crashing when i leave the textbox null c#

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;    
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.ComponentModel;    
using System.Data;    
using System.Drawing;    
using System.Linq;    
using System.Text;    
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IP_HULK
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int n1, n2, n3, n4;
            if (numbox1.Text == "" || numbox2.Text == "" || numbox3.Text == "" || numbox4.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("el ip fadi");
            }
            n1 = Convert.ToInt16(numbox1.Text);
            n2 = Convert.ToInt16(numbox2.Text);
            n3 = Convert.ToInt16(numbox3.Text);
            n4 = Convert.ToInt16(numbox4.Text);
            if ((n1 > 0 && n1 < 255) && (n2 > -1 && n2 < 255) && (n3 > -1 && n3 < 255) && (n4 > -1 && n4 < 255))
                            MessageBox.Show("The IP is Valid");
                        else
                            MessageBox.Show("The ip isn't valid");
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void numbox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use an `else` statement. Your logic says if the textboxes are empty, show a message. Once the user closes the MessageBox your program will attempt to convert the Textbox values regardless if they are empty or not.

As an example:

```
    int n1, n2, n3, n4;
    if (numbox1.Text == "" || numbox2.Text == "" || numbox3.Text == "" || numbox4.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("el ip fadi");
    }
    else 
    {
       n1 = Convert.ToInt16(numbox1.Text);
       n2 = Convert.ToInt16(numbox2.Text);
       n3 = Convert.ToInt16(numbox3.Text);
       n4 = Convert.ToInt16(numbox4.Text);
    }
```

However you are better off splitting this into a method which will perform the validation for you.  As an additional note can use [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than `Convert` and `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` which may be more readable.

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(numbox1.Text)) 
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int n1, n2, n3, n4;
if (!Int32.TryParse(numbox1.Text, out n1) || !Int32.TryParse(numbox2.Text, out n2) || 
    !Int32.TryParse(numbox3.Text, out n3) || !Int32.TryParse(numbox4.Text, out n4))
{
    MessageBox.Show("el ip fadi");
    return;
}
```

Use `TryParse` instead, as this *won't* crash if the data entered in invalid. Instead, it simply returns `true` or `false` (and "returns" the value of the conversion as an `out` parameter).

Additionally, since the rest of your code to convert the values occurs "in line" with the rest of the method, it continues to execute after your `MessageBox` appears. You could either enclose the rest of the method in an `else` block like Darren posted, or simply `return` after showing the `MessageBox` like I did here.

Also, you didn't "leave a textbox null",  you left it empty. `null` and `String.Empty` are **not** the same thing.